# Series: Let $S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ be an infinite series such that $S_N=4-\frac{2}{N^2}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ be an infinite series such that $S_N=4-\frac{2}{N^2}$.

(a) Find a general formula for $a_n$.

(b) Find the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$.

Can you explain to me how I can convert the partial sum to the general equation?

(a) What are the values of
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{10} a_n$ and $\sum\limits_{n=4}^{16} a_n$?

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{10} a_n=23433271/635040$

$\sum\limits_{n=4}^{16} a_n= 15799025474051/259718659200 $

(b) What is the value of $a_3$?
$167/18$

Why aren't these values correct as well?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some hints.

(a) You make $S_n$ by adding $a_n$ to $S_{n-1}$.

(b) What is the definition of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$?

Comment: I know that it's something-2/n^2 and I know that something is equal to -2/(N-1)^2 which is also equal to 4

Comment: I don't understand. What is "it" in your comment?

Comment: the value of SN-1

Comment: By definition, $S_{n-1}=4-2/(n-1)^2$. Right?

Comment: yes I agree with that

Comment: And what is $S_n$?

Comment: Ahhh I think I just realized what SN is. It's the N'th term of the partial sum right?

Comment: Yes! Sorry if that wasn't clear. This problem would be impossible if you didn't know it.

Comment: alright but How am I supposed to figure it out :S? I really don't know where to start from...

Answer (score 1):

Note that $S_{N}-S_{N-1}=a_N$, so that shall give you $a_n$

Comment: I don't get how that's it...

Comment: @user96246: use definition of $S_N$. $S_N=a_1+a_2+..a_N$. So, $S_{N+1}-S_N=a_1+a_2+..a_N+a_{N+1}-(a_1+a_2+..a_N)=a_{N+1}$

Comment: ok but how would you find SN+1?

Comment: @user96246: You have a formula for $S_n$, right? Put $n=N+1$ in yor formula.

Comment: But wouldn't that defy the limit? by limit i mean N approaching infinity?